# TikZ causes blank page in front of ConTeXt makeup with grid layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, context-mkiv, blank-page, grid-typesetting

Consider the following MWE:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]
\starttext
\startstandardmakeup
Not nothing.
\stopstandardmakeup
\stoptext
```

The output contains two pages: an unexpected and *undesired* blank, followed by a page containing the `makeup` block.

Removal of either `tikz`, `grid` or `makeup` is sufficient to make the blank disappear, but I can't give up any of them.

**Why and how are these three interacting?**

I am compiling with the latest TeXLive.

An excerpt from the log:

```
pages           > flushing realpage 1, userpage 1
pages           > flushing realpage 2, userpage 1
```

The `makeup` block should be on `userpage` 1. But it seems that *something* is pushing it and making the page overflow so it ends up on the next `realpage`.

Comment: maybe I am misinterpreting here, but your example does not produce any empty pages here. I get one page with `not nothing` printed, and no errors.

Comment: @runartrollet you're not misinterpreting me. I get no errors and a blank page. That's strange. I'm updating my TeXLive now. I'll report back later. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @runartrollet Done. Sadly the blank page is still in the output. Updating the question.

Comment: Confirmed on `context version: 2015.10.09`. I'll also check on a more recent version

Comment: Also confirmed on `context version: 2015.12.29`. I suggest that you report this bug on the mailing list.

Comment: @Aditya Reported. Thanks for the feedback. Let's hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer

This was a TikZ bug and it is fixed now.

## Old answer

Hans Hagen himself [explained to me](http://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/083942.html) that

> it's a bug in tikz ... it uses an extra file that needs to be opened
> immediate in order not to introduce an interfering node

He also offered a workaround:

> for now, in cont-new.mkiv put this:
>
> ```
> \unexpanded\def\openout{\immediate\normalopenout}
> ```

Note for simpletons like me: `cont-new.mkiv` is a `tex` file containing patches and experimental macros that `ConTeXt MKIV` loads at runtime. The workaround can also be used locally in your project, as long as it's inserted before `\usemodule[tikz]`.

Comment: A bugifx has been sent to the tikz maintainers, so hopefully this will be corrected in the next release of tikz.

Comment: This has now been fixed in TikZ.